# Singly linked-list class with constructors

Tags: c++

What I want to do is have a singly linked-list class with a default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment constructer, and destructor. I barely started it because I am confused if a `Node` with int data and next pointer should be a separate class or the way I did it.

```
class list {
public:
    list(): next(NULL) {} // default constructor                                   
    list(const list &t){} // copy constructor                                     
    list&   operator= (const list &t) // assignment operator                        
    ~list(){} //destructor                                                        
    void print()    

private:
    struct Node {
        data x;
        Node *next;
    }_list;
}
```

Comment: What confuses you exactly ? For the moment your code seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, logically, a node is a separate structure (class), but in common implementations, the list itself is represented by the first node.

So, basically, you wouldn't have a `list` class (and if you did, it'd just hold a pointer to the first node + the constructors/assignment operator/destructor):

```
struct Node {
  data x;
  Node *next;
};

class list{
 public:
  list(): next(NULL) {} // default constructor                                   
  list(const list &t){} // copy constructor                                     
  list& operator= (const list &t) // assignment operator                        
  ~list(){} //destructor                                                        
  void print() ;

 private:
  Node* first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "separate class" you mean not nested within *list*, then no, it's better for it to be nested (and private). But that doesn't mean you can't give it constructors, destructors, operators, methods, etc. (i.e. turn it into a full-blown class).

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid. If you use `Node` only in `list`, it is just an implementation detail. Although, if you need `Node` outside of `list`, e.g. in an `iterator` class, then you need to implement it outside of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Having an inner class is fine, however, if/when you implement methods like a constructor for the inner class, then the scope resolution operator needs to include the outer and inner class names. For example,

```
List::Node::Node(const DataType& nodeData, Node* nextPtr) {stuff}
```

By declaring the Node class in the private section of the List class you are providing encapsulation against external access, but still letting the List class have access.